# UIButton frame changed to garbage value after watching video ad

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, cgrect

I have a UIButton with 
`frame = (0,0,38,42)` 
I instantiate it during initialization of my view controller.
I don't add it immediately to the view. I only add it when i'm about to use it. In my case, when i click play button.

I have another button in my view controller which plays a video ad (vungle/ad colony)

During app load, when i watch a video ad before clicking play for the first time, the frame of my button becomes `frame = (-1.70141e+38 -1.70141e+38; 3.40282e+38 3.40282e+38)`

does anyone know why it happens? i can't even change it back to the original frame when i try to set the frame again.

my UIButton is a property. 
`@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton * button;`

during initialization of view controller:

```
- (id)init
{
 self = [super init];   
    if (self) {
        _button = [[UIButton alloc]init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

during loadView, i set the frame

```
_button.frame = CGRectMake(_button.frame.origin.x, _button.frame.origin.y, 38, 42);
```

---

i don't add it yet. i only add it when the play button is pressed. 
so something like

```
- (IBAction)playButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
   [self.view addSubview:_button];
}
```

Then, i have another button in my view controller. It displays video ad. When i play a video ad before clicking the play button, the frame becomes like what i displayed on top. but it only happens when i play video first before displaying _button.

Comment: show the code you have writtten

Comment: You should give more information about your button. How do you keep it in your class, instance or property? are you using ARC? you would better provide some code e.g. code where you create your button...

Comment: i'm using ARC. i've updated my question details.

Comment: What auto-resizing rules are applied to the view and how is the ad view shown (related to the main view)?

Comment: i think i found the problem. 
i have this code:
    CALayer *objectPresentationLayer = [_viewToAnimate.layer presentationLayer];
    _viewToAnimate.layer.transform = objectPresentationLayer.transform;

view to animate is my button above. I forgot to check if objectPresentationLayer is not nil. when i checked it a while ago, it was nil. When i assigned it to my view's layer, the frame got crazy. Do you know why it happens? When does a presentation layer gets committed?